# How To Set Background Image

Tags: html, css

I need to set this background image in my website for chrome and all other browser but in chrome it work perfect but in firefox and other browser doesn't work perfectly. Even for firefox I tried the -moz- tag but doesn't work.

```
{
    position: relative;
    background:url(backgrdnd2.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    -moz-background-size:100% 100%;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: what kind of "not working perfectly" are you talking about? What was the problem?

Comment: i mean the picture doesnt cover the whole background. i tried the background-size:cover; method too,it works for fire fox but having the same problem in internetexplorer.
http://imgur.com/2reES5R its in the internet explorer
http://imgur.com/RjxEuLc and this look perfect in chrome and firefox

Comment: weird, because I just tried the `background-size: 100% 100%` and it worked perfectly on Firefox, my guess is that something else is messing up with it. Can you give me your website so I can check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try backgroud-size:cover;

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size:cover;
background-size: cover;
```

for the rest of the browsers

hope it helps.

Comment: thankss it helps me for firefox . but the IE still have problems.

Comment: i tried this it works for fire fox but not for internet explorer.
http://imgur.com/2reES5R its in the internet explorer
http://imgur.com/RjxEuLc and this look perfect in chrome

Comment: http://www53.zippyshare.com/v/18831950/file.html check it. i uploaded it to zippyshare

Answer (score 0):

The background property is supported in all major browsers.  See: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

I'm not sure what element you are applying these styles on, but perhaps that element has no height or width? Try inspecting the element in Chrome or using Firebug in Firefox to determine if your background image is loading, and whether or not the element you are applying the background to is visible.

Answer (score 0):

First, in your css you should put the selector, where do you want to apply the style, for example the body

```
body {
    position: relative;
    background:url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-m7blv8kfKxs/UiAWmV9uJXI/AAAAAAAAJos/RsYP_YC9FbY/s1600/Background-Textures2.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

check this link for more information about selectors.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

I also used @EduadoRobles suggestion, check this

http://jsfiddle.net/agusgambina/A8nmp/

Comment: samething imgur.com/2reES5R in IE and imgur.com/RjxEuLc in firefox and chrome they work perfect .it covers the whole background with image but in IE it doesnt cover the whole page.

Comment: http://www53.zippyshare.com/v/18831950/file.html check it. i uploaded it to zippyshare

Comment: I don't have IE.Maybe you should try something like this for IE
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/someimage.png',sizingMethod='scale')";